# Access headers in AWS API Gateway using HTTP Proxy?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS API Gateway and it's HTTP Proxy,

I need to pass Authorization header to my endpoint through AWS API Gateway

Things I've tried:

Setting Method Request like so,

[image: Method Request]

Integration Request setup
[image]

This doesn't work, my app doesn't receive the Authorization header,

Also I've tried using mapping template

```
{
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "queryParams": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "pathParams": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  }  
}
```

This also doesn't work.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I had to try using an API Gateway HTTP proxy to pass an AWS SigV4 HTTP request to an endpoint. 
After testing and debugging found that the Authorization is being consumed and not passed! 
So while sending the request to the API Gateway - I sent Authorization and a copy of the Authorization as another header "myauth". (I was able to do this since the request is coming from my own client.)

In the method request I added Authorization and myauth as HTTP Headers
[Method Request - HTTP Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X12so.png)

In the Integration Request - HTTP Headers I mapped myauth to Authorization before it was forwarded to the endpoint

[Integration Request - HTTP Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAFd1.png)

Dont know if this is the best way to do this or if there could be any potential issues but this worked! Hope this helps someone or gives some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

API Gateway strips the AWS SigV4 Authorization header due to security reasons. If you are using other Authorization mechanism like OAuth, the header wouldn't be stripped.

Comment: So I may assume that it's impossible to pass Authorization header?

Comment: @user3384147: Sorry for the delayed response. It is possible to pass Authorization header if you are using any Authorization other than AWS SigV4. When you use SigV4, AWS consumes the Authorization header and hence strips it. What Authorization are you using?

Comment: I am trying to protect the API by forcing my clients to use endpoint-url in boto to point at my APIGw, I then intercept the call and validate some of the params passed to the API (which IAM does not support / have any condition keys for currently), I will also validate their sig4v (because our service gave them the keys) if the request looks OK , I will pass it onto the API using my lambdas IAM role to actually execute it. But to do that I would prefer to see the Sigv4 otherwise they can't use the native toolchain like awscli to call the service and would need custom auth any Idea?