# Accessing cloudfront-viewer-country header in AWS API Gateway using HTTP Proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS API Gateway and its HTTP Proxy.

I need to pass the `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` header to my endpoint. I tried following the same setup outlined in the following question
[Access headers in AWS API Gateway using HTTP Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017297/access-headers-in-aws-api-gateway-using-http-proxy)

and I'm getting the following headers on my endpoint server.

```html
Array
(
    [host] => example.com
    [Accept] => application/json
    [User-Agent] => AmazonAPIGateway_c8752844lh
    [x-amzn-apigateway-api-id] => c8752844lh
    [X-Amzn-Trace-Id] => Root=1-59bd7a5e-003ef07b3c4c3680299801f1
    [X-Forwarded-For] => xx.xxx.xx.xxx
    [X-Forwarded-Port] => 443
    [X-Forwarded-Proto] => https
    [Connection] => keep-alive

)
```

However, the `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` is not among them. If I used a lambda function instead of HTTP Proxy, I can see a lot more headers (including the `CloudFront-Viewer-Country`).

Could anyone please tell me how to access the required header on my endpoint using HTTP Proxy ?

Answer (score 11):

For the resource and method where you want the header, go to Method Request → HTTP Request Headers → Add Header and set the Name as `CloudFront-Viewer-Country`.  Click the circled checkmark to add.  This exposed the header to the remainder of the execution flow.

Then, in Integration Request → HTTP Headers → Add Header.

Set the Name to `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` and set Mapped from `method.request.header.CloudFront-Viewer-Country` and click the circled checkmark to add.  This picks up the exposed header and adds it to the request that is forwarded to your back-end.

Deploy the API.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply creating a new integration header named `Accept-Encoding` with value equal to `'identity'`
And all the missing headers appeared !!