# How to get location and country name in AWS Lambda events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

To get IP address I use something like this

```
event.requestContext.identity.sourceIp
```

How do I get location and country similar to this?

I was trying something like this:

```
event.requestContext.location
```

Comment: By using some 3rd party service that provides an IP -> country lookup. Or maybe by relying on CloudFront https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318725/geolocation-service-with-aws-api-gateway-and-lambda .

Comment: That information is not provided to the Lambda function. You will need to obtain that information from an external service.

Answer (score 0):

How is your Lambda being invoked?

If you are using API Gateway, you should be able to see Cloudfront headers in the event data, assuming you use the Lambda Proxy integration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-cloudfront-headers.html#cloudfront-headers-viewer-location